# Afnetworking Batch vs Multiple Post Request

Tags: ios, mysql, afnetworking-2

I have an application similar to tinder in that you can swipe left and right. Tinder say's it saves all swipes to its database. I need to do the same so I want to know if after swiping all of objects left or right should I create an AFHTTPRequestOperation for each swipe and save that in an array after the swiping is complete then send all request in a batch before I get new objects. Or should I send a post request with each swipe. I have this iOS app connected to a Node Js. app that connects to a MySQL database. Node can easily handle thousands of requests but I want to know which is the best design.

Comment: were you able to do it?

Comment: @RicardoAlves I ended up sending the request to a queue to be processed in order instead of creating individual requests which give me the benefit of not having to worry about the request once I send the off to the queue because the queue would process them, I all did was handle to post callback from the Node end